# Find a name on a string based on a name mysql table

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, request

I have a table with a title string for each entry. I try to find if the name of a politician is present in this string.

For that, i try to compare each string with another table where i have the name of politicians.

For now, i do that :

```
$req = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM mystrings") 
 or die('Error : '.$sql.'<br/>'.mysql_error()); 

 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) 
{
     $thestring = stripslashes($data['thestring']);
     $thestring2 = str_replace(' ', '%', $thestring);
     $firstname = "";
     $lastname = "";

  $req2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM politicians WHERE nom LIKE '$thestring2'")or die('Error     '.mysql_error());

  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req2)) 
      {
          $firstname = stripslashes($data['firstname']);
          $lastname = stripslashes($data['lastname']);

        echo 'this guy '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'is on this string : '.$thestring ;

      }
 }
```

I made these two queries as well because I want to be able to detect if there are several politicians in my sentence, not just one, and to have their full name for all.

I think my method is not good, but I do not find the solution ...
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make function on Database like:

Algoritm only

```
FOR mydata IN SELECT thestring FROM mystrings
 LOOP
   SELECT firstname,lastname FROM politicians WHERE nom LIKE thestring;
 ENDLOOP
ENDFOR
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is "mydata" ? I have never heard about SQL Loop. I'll check that !

Comment: mydata is You personal variable for example You can name as mysweetdata and nex in LOOP try  mydata.thestring   If You named mysweetdata You must use  mysweetdata.thestring